# Issue with long division of 1/n

Tags: python, loops, math, division

I've written the following code to return the repetends for 1/n. It basically performs long division until it hits a repeat dividend. Calling `repetends(n)` directly returns the correct results, e.g. `repetends(7)` returns `(True, '142857')`, meaning that 1/7 does have an infinitely repeating decimal repetend of 142857.

However, when I call `list_repetends(10)`, which simply calls `repetends` in a for loop ascending to some n, I get totally different -- and incorrect -- results from individually calling `repetends` on n = 1, 2, 3 ... 10.

Here are the results I'm getting, followed by the code. Any idea why a simple for loop is screwing up my results?

**n, repetends(n), list_repetends(10):**

1 (False, '1') (False, '1')

2 (False, '5') (False, '15')

3 (True, '3') (True, '3')

4 (False, '25') (True, '3')

5 (False, '2') (True, '3')

6 (True, '6') (True, '3')

7 (True, '142857') (True, '3')

8 (False, '125') (True, '3')

9 (True, '1') (True, '3')

10 (False, '1') (True, '3')

```
f = ''
remainders = {}

# n = numerator (1), d = denominator, z = tracks dropped zeros

def longdiv(n, d, z):
    global remainders
    global f
    if n in remainders:
        return True, f[remainders[n]:]
    mod = n % d
    if mod == n:
        if z >= 1:
            f += '0'
        z += 1
        return "Cont", (10*n, d, z)
    else:
        if mod == 0:
            f += str(n/d)
            return False, f
        else:
            r = n - mod
            dec = r/d
            f += str(dec)
            if n not in remainders:
                remainders[n] = len(f)-1
            return "Cont", (mod, d, 0)

def repetends(n):
    div, rem = longdiv(1,n,0)
    if div == True or div == False:
        return div, rem
    else:
        while div == "Cont":
            mod, d, z = rem
            div, rem = longdiv(mod,n,z)
        return div, rem

def list_repetends(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print repetends(i)
```

Comment: Your use of the global variable `remainders` is what's tripping you up. Instead, try keeping it strictly within the scope of `longdiv`

Comment: There are better ways to do "memoization", check the https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary for snippets that cache function results.